# My app is working on Expo Go, but apk crashes when I open page with map component

Tags: react-native, expo, mapview

I finished my app and it is working in Expo Go, but when I export apk to test it, it crashes when I open page with map component. I did all instructions from: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/
The error I get in eas development build is:
`FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/projects/1e87f42e-7cda-4e6d-a836-2f70ed36d59f failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.expo.dev`
When I remove mapview component my apk is completely working. This is in my app.json file:

```
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION",
    "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
    "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
    "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
  ],
  "package": "---------------------",
  "config": {
    "googleMaps":{
      "apiKey": "-------------------------------"
    }
  }
```

And this is how I use MapView:

```
 <MapView 
      style={styles.map}
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} > 
      {attractions?.map((attraction) => (
      <Marker coordinate = {
                  {
                    latitude: attraction.location.lat,
                    longitude: attraction.location.lng
                  }
              
            }
            key={attraction.id}
            
           
            >
            <Callout
              onPress={() => newChat(attraction.title)}
            >
            
                    
                    <Text >{attraction.title}</Text>
                </Callout>
            </Marker>))}
     
      </MapView>
```